# Redirected to /cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi

Tags: redirect, centos, http-status-code-404, cpanel

I have a cpanel account under directory:

```
/home/username/
```

and a single file under:

```
/home/username/public_html/
```

which is `index.php`

which contains:

```
<?php
header("Location: https://www.facebook.com/.../");
```

I am using CentOS server and this worked well until today. However now it redirects me to (Default Web Site Page):

```
username.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi
```

I am unable to figure out what caused this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is an issues with your cPanel account setup and due to that you site is not showing content from /home/username/public_html/ directory, Might be there is misconfiguration with the site IP OR DNS, Please try to check your site with temp URL and check it (http://Server_IP/~username/)

Comment: 404 when I try to reach `serverip/username`

Comment: It is possible that, this is due to cPanel account setup.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using https for your domain please check if your certificate is valid. It might be you have installed a SSL certificate on a shared IP address.